# Loop in view is showing more result as expected by calling super(value.to_s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am running Rails 3 with the following code in the view

**View**:

```
<%= @found_docs.each do |doc| %>
<%= doc.id  | doc.content %>
<% end %>
```

As a result I get two objects, as expected - but in addition a third result is displayed. It is created by calling super(value.to_s) on the result set. Doing @founds_doc.count returns 2 as expected.

Why is the third object displayed when running the block, when @found_docs has only two objects ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - and I did a silly mistake !
The view code is as follow:

```
<%= @found_docs.each do |doc| %>
```

I put the "=" sign in front of the loop, hence the result of the loop is printed with value.to_s in the view.

Correct code is:

```
<% @found_docs.each do |doc|%>
```

Must have been blind :-)